What is the pattern in the sequence? -1, 3/2, -13/6, 25/8
It happens to be useful to me to understand the pattern in this list of numbers:
$$-1, \frac{3}{2}, -\frac{13}6, \frac{25}8, -\frac{541}{120}, \frac{1561}{240}, -\frac{47293}{5040}, \frac{36389}{2688}, -\frac{7087261}{362880} ...$$
I have tried looking in the OEIS, but have turned up empty handed. I do not have reason to expect the terms in the series to be particularly messy to calculate, at worst, sums and products of factorials.

If you un-reduce the fractions such that the denominators are the factorials in order, the numerators appear to be a signed version of A000670.

@AxiomaticSystem Well, that's the answer. I was so stuck on this puzzle until I saw your comment. Maybe you should post it as an answer.

You should consider

 not reducing these fractions:
$\frac{-1}{1!}, \frac{3}{2!}, \frac{-13}{3!}, \frac{75}{4!}, \frac{-541}{5!}, \frac{4683}{6!}, \frac{-47293}{7!}, \frac{545835}{8!}, \frac{7087261}{9!}, \dots$
 The (unsigned) numerators form the sequence of Fubini numbers, which are in the OEIS after all.

 As for the alternating signs and the divisions by factorials, I could only attempt to explain those due to a comment on the linked page that the Fubini numbers have exponential generating function $\frac{1}{2-e^x}$. Some algebraic manipulation to account for sign yields that your sequence corresponds to the ordinary generating function $\frac{1}{e^{-x}-2}$.

